# How do I reset a select menu when focus is lost?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have my 'search class' menus reset to default once it loses focus as I have several 'select' menus operated by the following and everything works when switching between different 'choice class' menus but not when using different 'search class' menus within the same 'choice class menu'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.search').hide();
    $('#start').show();
    $('.window').change(function () {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    $('.choice').change(function () {
        $('.search').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show().find('option:first-child').attr({ selected : true, disabled : true }).trigger("change");
    })
});
```

My problem is that once the first 'search class' menu loses focus and another is chosen and used to display the attached div, the previous menu is still on that choice once you return to it you can't select that option again before choosing another one first.

Here's a short version of my Select if it helps build a picture

```
<div class="search" id="family">
  <select class="window">
    <option>
      --Please make a selection--
    </option>
    <option value="clear">
      --Clear--
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="search" id="type">
  <select class="window">
    <option>
      --Please make a selection--
    </option>
    <option value="full">
      --Full--
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want any 'search class' menu that loses focus to return to the first option. Maybe I should be using .focusout(function() but I don't understand the language well enough to know what I'm doing right or wrong.

EDITED to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved my problem after several days of feeling defeated, this is my solution

```
    $("select").blur(function () {
        $(this).find('option:first-child').attr({ selected : true, disabled : true });
    })
```

Which I then added to what I already had above.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.search').hide();
    $('#start').show();
    $('.window').change(function () {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    $('.choice').change(function () {
        $('.search').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    $("select").blur(function () {
        $(this).find('option:first-child').attr({ selected : true, disabled : true });
    })
});
```

All thanks to user4723924 for refreshing the way I was looking at my problem.

EDIT: My fix works with jQuery v1.3.2, which is what I was using.
I tried using jQuery v3.3.1 and it stopped working. I don't know or understand why. I'll see if I can figure out a fix that works with most recent version of jQuery and post it here once found.

EDITEDIT:
This works with jQuery v3.3.1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.search').hide();
    $('#start').show();
    $('.window').change(function () {
        $('.panel').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    $('.choice').change(function () {
        $('.search').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
    $("select").blur(function () {
        $(this).find('option:first-child').prop("selected", "selected");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a select's value like this...

```
YourID.selectedIndex=3;
```

For example...

```
<select id="abc" onchange="SomeFunc(this.value); this.selectedIndex=0;">
 <option value="0" selected>click to select</option>
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3">three</option>
 <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Interesting, though I would have to add one for every separate id. I have 6 'choice class' menus but many more 'search class' menu than I can count at the moment. Can this work with class instead of ids?EDIT: I've tried     $('.search').selectedIndex=1; but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've demonstrated above how to use this to your advantage.

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you with those $ signs, I don’t use 3rd party libs.

Comment: Don't need to be sorry. If i had fewer 'search class' menus, I'd probably have a fix already but you've definitely given me some ideas that I am exploring right now. :)